# JS OOP Form Module to add sibling select elements

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, form

How can it be more cross-browser compatible, robust, better performance if possible?

```
var Form={
   /*QA :
     Goals : Cross browser compliant 2.DRYness 3. performant 
   */
  formObjects:{

        enumObjects : function(){

            for(var i=0; i < this.length; i++){

                console.log(this[i]);
            }

        },

     },


  categories:{

    properties:['Houses','Apartments','Commercial Property', 'Land/Plots'],
    vehicles:['Sedans', 'Hatchbacks', 'SUVs', 'Pickups and Double-Cabs','Vans','Trucks and Lorries',
              'Vans', 'Buses', 'Motorcycles'],
    electronics:['Desktop Computers','Laptops and Tablets','Stereo and Home Theatre Systems','Cellphones','Networking Equipment','Other'],
    services:['Medical','Dental','Legal','Financial Services','Printing and Professional Services','Auto Service','Vehicle Rental','Equipment Rentals','Electrical/Plumbing','Carpentry'],
    travel:['Accomodation', 'Lodges/Cabins','Travel Agents', 'Safaris/Tours','Taxis/Shuttle Services']

  },


  cityareas:{
                      Blantyre: [ 'All','Bangwe','Che Mussa','Chirimba','Chadzunda','Chilomoni','Manase','Mpemba','Mbayani',
                        'Mpingwe','New Land','Mudi','Manyowe','Chatha','Kachere','Sunny Side',
                        'Nancholi','Nkolokoti','Nyambadwe','Kameza','Machinjiri',
                        'Chileka','Chigumula','Chichiri','Chinyonga','Kanjedza','Kampala',
                        'Manja','Limbe','Nkolokosa','Naperi','Chitawira','Ndirande',
                        'Goliyo','C.I','Chilobwe','Mount Pleasant','Baluti','Green Corner','Stella Maris'],

                    Mzuzu:['All','Katawa','Chasefu','Nkhorongo','Chiputula','Chiwavi','Zolozolo',
                    'Masasa','Mchengautuwa','Hilltop','Lupaso','Luwinga','Area 1b','Area4'],

                    Lilongwe:['All','Bunda','Chiwoko','Kabudula','Ntandile','Gaga','Ntsinje',
                      'Namichimba','Gologota','Tambalale','Lumbadzi', 'Biwi','Chilinde','Kawale','Chipasula','Mwenyekondo','Falls','Likuni','Chisapo','Chigwili','Katete','Nkhoma',
                      'Nanjiri','Kanengo','Msambachiko','Nathenje','Chiwuzila','Airwing','Chitedze','Nsundwe',
                      'Namitete']
                  },


     /*
    1. get selection from catselect, clear form, create child select element with eventlistner.
     When child div is selected, check if it has children and create new form select element from that
     */
     findForms:function(){

          var formObjs=document.forms;
          var arr=[];
          //assign key value for each child element into formobjects
         for(var i=0; i< formObjs.length; i++ ){   
            this.formObjects[formObjs[i].name]=Array.prototype.slice.call(formObjs[i].children);      
        };

       },


     selParent: function(elValue, el)
       {    
           for (var prop in this) 
            {    
             this[prop].hasOwnProperty(elValue) ? this.childSel(this[prop][elValue], el) : ' ';                                                                        
            };

        }, 


     childSel : function(nodeVal, refNode) {

        if( (refNode.nextElementSibling !=null) && (refNode.nextElementSibling.name == 'subcats' ) )
         {
           /*
           if sibling exists, remove entries and enter new entries
          */
            var siblingEl=document.getElementById(refNode.nextElementSibling.id);
            siblingEl.options.length=0;

            for(var i=0; i< nodeVal.length; i++)
            {
                    var option=document.createElement('option');
                    option.text=nodeVal[i];                    
                    siblingEl.add(option,siblingEl[i]); 
            } 

         } else{ 

            var siblingEl = document.createElement('select');
            siblingEl.id = refNode.value;
            siblingEl.name='subcats';
            refNode.parentNode.insertBefore(siblingEl, refNode.nextElementSibling);

            for(var i=0; i< nodeVal.length; i++)
            {                
                   var option=document.createElement('option');
                   option.text=nodeVal[i];
                   siblingEl.add(option,siblingEl[i]);
            }

         }

     },           

     init: function(){

             var i=0, objForm=this;
             this.findForms(); //initialises the form objects

             for(key in this.formObjects){
                 for (var i=0; i<this.formObjects[key].length; i++){
                      if(this.formObjects[key][i].nodeName=='SELECT'){
                        var selId=document.getElementById(this.formObjects[key][i].id);

                      //value of *this* changes to target element in addEventListener
                      selId.addEventListener('change',
                        function(event)
                        { 
                          var item=this.value;
                          objForm.selParent(item,this);
                          event.stopPropagation();
                        },
                        false );

                      }
                    }
             i++;

           };

     } //End Init

}
```

Comment: May I suggest that you add a demo? Press Ctrl-M in the question editor.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to split into simple pure functions doing one thing each. Search for Robert Martin aka Uncle Bob advices on clean code.

Is this just a helper to display an array:

```
enumObjects = array.forEach(console.log)
```

Then import it from your general helper library.
Also why is it so deeply nested?

Any plain JSON data objects I would store separately and import into your module. The module should not depend on any specific data for better testability.

Pure functions without side-effects are even easier to test, so I would put there as much code as possible. That will help you to simplify your module by importing those functions.

Also I would import all globals such as `document` as parameters, the fewer dependencies the more reusable and testable is your module.